# Firestore/Firebase not working with Next.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Hey y'all really struggling here.

I am trying use firebase in my Next.js app, specifically for the api. It works fine when I build production locally, and on local development. But once I deploy to production on the vercel platform I get a `500 - Internal Server Error`. I have been able to narrow down the error to it being being caused by using `await getDocs(q)` but not sure how to fix it.

Essentially I am trying to do dynamic api routing with data from firestore.

`firebase.js`:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>",
  authDomain: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>",
  databaseURL: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>",
  projectId: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>",
  storageBucket: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>",
  messagingSenderId: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>",
  appId: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>",
  measurementId: "<REDACTED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW>"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Database
const db = getFirestore();
// Storage
const storage = getStorage(app)

export {
  app,
  storage,
  db
}
```

`/api/users/[name].js`:

```
import { db } from './firebase.js'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const { name } = req.query
    let users = []
    const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("name", "==", name))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
      res.status(404).json({error: "Document does not exist."})
    } else {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        users.push(doc.data())
      })
      res.status(200).json(users)
    }
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(404).json({error: err})
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.2",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "next": "11.0.1",
    "firebase": "^9.5.0",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^8.0.11",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.5",
    "postcss-nesting": "^8.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^6.0.2",
    "react-pro-sidebar": "^0.6.0",
    "react-remark": "^2.0.3",
    "rehype-raw": "^5.1.0",
    "rehype-react": "^6.2.1",
    "remark-html": "^13.0.1",
    "remark-react": "^8.0.0",
    "remark-rehype": "^8.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.35.1",
    "xhr2": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "eslint": "7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

The error on the server side starts off like this:
`@firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.5.0): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/src/protos/google/firestore/v1/firestore.proto'`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2320#issuecomment-583731130) can help you.

Comment: This seems more directed to Angular, unless there is something equivalent in Next.js that I don't know about? @Ashish

Comment: can you share `package.json` ?

Comment: @ChemiAdel just added it :)

Comment: @MarioLopez firebase should be defined in package.json so that server will install it, I put an answer if it worked don't forget to marked as an answer

Comment: @ChemiAdel just updated the package.json, I showed the wrong one. It was from a different branch

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading firebase to 9.4.0 solves the exact issue for me. I'm not sure if it's a good fix, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that somehow the dependencies was installed in local package `node_modules` but not defined on package.json.

You need to define it on package.json so it will be installed on the building stage

on project folder, open terminal and install it so it will be added in the package :

```
npm install --save firebase
```

Comment: Oh so sorry this was a the wrong package.json (was on a different branch). Let me put the correct one.

Comment: Just updated it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this, if you are using `handler` function in `getServerSideProps` or other functions in `index.js`, try using the code below:

```
const q = query(collection(getFirestore(app), "users"), where("name", "==", name))
```

This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue for a while.
The problem is that you are using the approach to initializeApp in the client.

for a nodejs, or server based initailization do this:

- go to firebase console, and in Project Settings > service account, export a new key (that export a json file, that you should sit in the root of the project)
- then create utils/db.js and inside import that json file and initialize the app:

```
import serviceAccount from "./file.json";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  try {
    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Firebase admin initialization error", error.stack);
  }
}
export default admin.firestore();
```

wala. If you use both, SSR and CSR, keep both approaches for client side and server side firebase connnection.

then in your pages/api/whetever.js

```
import db from "/utils/db.js";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const entries = await db.collection("collection").get();
    const entriesData = entries.docs.map((entry) => ({
      id: entry.id,
      ...entry.data(),
    }));
    res.status(200).json({ entriesData });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).end();
  }
}
```

test by calling localhost:3000/api/whatever